# Can minecraft be played only on 64-bit computers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have a 32-bit computer and I downloaded Minecraft and tried to play the demo. But when I started it, it said something like 'Error: could not initialize jvm 64' or something. So does that mean Minecraft can be played on only 64-bit? I really want to play Minecraft. Is there a 32-bit version or something?

Comment: Question is OK, but a new user named "Programming coder" asking about something like this... makes me wonder.

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of computer and OS you actually have? (“32-bit computer” doesn't tell us enough.) Also, what version(s) of Java do you have installed?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I use a windows 10 32-bit computer and I have installed java version 1.8.0.

Comment: @Rudolf L. Jelinek I actually came to stackexchange to ask programming questions at stackoverflow. But I had no idea how big stackexchange is.

Comment: @Programmingcoder Ok :) Actually, me too!

Comment: @Rudolf L. Jelinek And besides, minecraft was created by programmers wasn't it? :).

Comment: Java version 1.8.0? I don't know what that means. But I do know that Minecraft runs on it's own independent .jar, can you confirm @SevenSidedDie ?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Oh, that's right, it bundles its own JVM now. Nevermind! :)

Comment: But why doesn't it work?

Comment: @KevinL That would be “Minecraft Windows 10 Edition”. Yeah, Programming coder, can you confirm which edition of Minecraft you downloaded?

Comment: @Programmingcoder We're still trying to gather all the details necessary to understand what's actually on your computer, what steps you've done, what the error is, etc. [Edit]ing your question to include more details, and maybe the step-by-step way that you can reproducibly cause the error (and a more exact quote of the error, or screenshots) would help. When answers start being given, they won't be in these tiny comment boxes, they'll be below, and look more like the question post in size and layout.

Comment: I saw that in my ProgramFiles(x86) folder, where I downloaded minecraft had a folder called runtime and in it was jaja -x64. So is the included java 64 bit? So will replacing that folder with the original java folder I have work?

Answer (score 3):

Try reinstalling Java, and make sure that you have the **32x** version installed. If this does not work, try opening the Minecraft launcher. Click "edit profile" on the lower part of the launcher window. Another window should pop up. In this window, check the box labeled "JVM Arguments." Where it says -Xmx(Number)G. Replace (number) with half of the number of gigabytes of RAM. If it is already so, or greater, increase it. If this does not work, try downloading [this](https://launcher.mojang.com/mc/game/1.5.2/client/465378c9dc2f779ae1d6e8046ebc46fb53a57968/client.jar) minecraft launcher version, and completing the JVM Argument step again.

Comment: But the JVM runtime folder is provided with minecraft. I have already tried reinstalling java (32-bit) many times.

Comment: I did some other stuff and now I can do it!

Comment: Great to hear! You may want to answer your own question to help others out!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it was not working was that the java included with minecraft was 64-bit. I replaced the file in ProgramFiles > Minecraft > runtime > java x64 > 1.8.0 with the java files on my computer.